# Possible to change Win 8 behaviour of launching apps?

Tags: windows, windows-8

If I hit the windows key, type `notepad` and hit enter, it'll launch a new notepad instance.

If I already had a notepad instance open, however, it'll revert to that.

Is it possible to simply have Windows launch a new notepad instance every time I select it from the metro menu?

Reason: It's most intuitive (for me personally, at least) to look to the taskbar to revert to a running app, and to use the metro/start menu to launch a new one.

Comment: You can also SHIFT+Click on the already open application's icon in the taskbar to open a new instance. Works since Vista.

Answer (score 1):

Found the answer, can be changed (permanently) with a registry change:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\ImmersiveShell\Launcher

DesktopAppsAlwaysLaunchNewInstance DWORD

0 = Disable
1 = Enable
```

http://www.eightforums.com/tutorials/49581-desktop-apps-always-open-new-instance-start-screen.html